# Get data from multiple tables to an object with LINQ join

Tags: linq, inner-join, multiple-tables

I am trying to get from 3 related tables by using LINQ. But when I use 2 joins, the result takes only elements getting from 2nd join. Here is my code:

```
var myAssList = mldb.Assigns
                .Join(mldb.Lists,
                      a => a.list_id,
                      l => l.id,
                      (a, l) => new {
                         Assign = a,
                         List = l 
                     })                
                .Where(a => a.Assign.assigned_to == "myname")
                .Join(mldb.Elements,
                      li => li.List.id,
                      e => e.parent_server_id,
                      (li, e) => new { 
                         Element = e 
                      });

var jsonSerialiser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var listListJson = jsonSerialiser.Serialize(myAssList);
```

this Json return only attributes from Element(e) and List(li). But I want to get also the attributes from Assign(a).

The SQL query I am trying to realize in  LINQ is that:

```
select * from Assigns 

inner join Lists 
on Assigns.server_list_id=Lists.id

inner join Elements
on Lists.id=Elements.parent_id

where Assigns.assigned_to='myname'
```

So, how can I get the attributes from the first join also (from "a", "l" and "e")?

Comment: Is it required to use lambda syntax? Query syntax looks much better with joins

Comment: What is the difference between lambda and query syntax? Is it effects performance or usability? I really don't know the difference. I just used to write like that.

Comment: Performance is same, because query syntax translated into lambdas by compiler. Query syntax is more readable. Lambda syntax allows you to build query dynamically - adding or removing filters or other operators based on conditions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access `Assign` entity from outer sequence `li` variable:

```
.Join(mldb.Elements,
      li => li.List.id,
      e => e.parent_server_id,
      (li, e) => new { 
         Element = e,
         Assign = li.Assign // here
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from a in mldb.Assigns
join l in mldb.Lists on a.list_id equals l.id
join e in mldb.Elements on l.id equals e.parent_server_id
where a => a.Assign.assigned_to == "myname"
select new { Assign = a, Element = e }
```

This is so called "query syntax". It makes LINQ expressions looks like SQL queries.
In the end they are translated to `IEnumerable` extension methods. If you want
to join multiple tables then query syntax is more readable. Another useful feature
of query syntax is `let` clause. With the aid of it, you can declare additional variables
inside your queries.

Comment: Perhaps just add some explanation. Think of the future visitors who may not be that familiar with the language but still want to achieve the same behaviour.